# Stuck on proving two quite simple results using modular arithmetic and factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Hello I'm trying to do two problems but can't seem to get the proofs myself, any help is appreciated. I know the definitions of congruence, definition of a factor and Bezout's lemma I've tried using these and manipulating these to get what I want but I can't seem to get to the final answer.

> 1. Suppose that $c$ is coprime to $n$ and $ac \equiv bc \pmod n$. Prove that $a \equiv b \pmod n$.
> 2. Suppose that $ac \equiv b \pmod n$. Prove that $\operatorname{hcf}(a,n)|b$.

Comment: For the first, $n$ divides $c(a-b)$. Since $c$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $n$ divides $a-b$.  You may already know the relevant lemma (Euclid's Lemma). If not, you can prove it using Bezout.  It would have been useful to know what you had tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first point, if you know Euler's theorem, it's easy: $c$ is invertible modulo $n$ (this can be proved with Bézout identity). Hence
$$ac\equiv bc\mod n\rightarrow acc^{-1}\equiv bcc^{-1}\mod n.$$
For the second point, let $d=\gcd(c,n)$, and write $a=da'$, $n=dn'$ ($\gcd(a',n')=1$). We have $da'c=b+kdn'$ for some integer $k$, so 
$$b=d(a'c-kn').$$